# Handling string operations (and testing the result of grep) in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, touchpad

I have written this script to toggle my touchpad (I will be keybinding it),
but it's not working. 
Why is this code not working? 
And how can I accomplish this function more elegantly?

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'" ]
then
        synclient TouchpadOff=0
        notify-send "Touchpad Enabled"
else
        synclient TouchpadOff=1
        notify-send "Touchpad Disabled"
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

When you write

```
 if [ "some string or other" ]
 then
```

the `[` operator doesn't run `some string or other`, it just sees a non-empty string and says that is a `true` value.

You want

```
 if [ "`synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'`" ]
```

or the more modern

```
if [ "$(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')" ]
```

but there is really no need to see if the command produces a string as grep produces an exit code so

```
if synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep -q -E '[0-9]+'
then
```

should do what you want. I don't know the output format of synclient, but I would expect you could combine the two greps into one without too much effort.

Comment: To combine both grep: `synclient | grep -oP '\s*TouchpadOff\s*=\s*\K[0-9]+'`

Comment: @Isaac Is this because you know the output format of synclient, or is this a guess?

Comment: I do know the output of synclient. I am not guessing.

Answer (score 3):

icarus gave [a pretty good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/527585/80216#527588). 
Your question is hard to answer
because you don’t explain exactly what the script is supposed to be doing,
so we are forced to reverse-engineer it (and guess what you are thinking).

icarus guessed that you are looking to see
whether the output from `synclient` includes a line
that contains “TouchpadOff” and a number.

I guess that you are assuming / expecting
that the output from `synclient` includes a line
that contains “TouchpadOff” and a number,
and you are looking to see whether that number is 0.

If icarus guessed correctly, stop reading.

If I guessed correctly,
we can adapt the penultimate (second-to-last) command
in [icarus’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/527585/80216#527588) as follows:

```
if [ "$(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')" != 0 ]
```

(to test whether the number is zero) and this should be fairly portable. 
But there may be a couple of shorter ways:

- If you’re using bash, you can do

  ```
  if (( "$(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')" ))
  ```

  using the `(( expression ))` syntax. 
  Problems with this include:

  - It’s not POSIX-compliant, and so behavior in shells other than bash
    will have to be looked at on a case-by-case basis.
  - If the output from the command is null, it is treated as 0.
- If you know more about what the output from `synclient` looks like
  than you are showing, you can write a smarter `grep`. 
  For instance, if you’re fairly certain that the output from `synclient`
  will contain a line that contains a string
  that looks like `TouchpadOff = number`,
  where *`number`* is a non-negative integer with no leading zero
  (i.e., it might be `0`, `1`, or `42`, but not `01`, `0.5`, or `off`),
  and there might or might not be space(s) before and/or after the `=`,
  then you can do

  ```
  if ! synclient | grep -q 'TouchpadOff[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*0'
  ```

  In some versions of `grep` (e.g., GNU `grep`), you can shorten that to

  ```
  if ! synclient | grep -q 'TouchpadOff\s*=\s*0'
  ```

  I added the `!` to reverse the truth value of the command. 
  `grep -q 'TouchpadOff…=…0'` will (obviously) succeed
  if it finds `TouchpadOff = 0` — but, if my guess is correct,
  you want to do the

  ```
  synclient TouchpadOff=0
  ```

  command if the current value is ***not*** zero.